# How to compare JSON Response with Postman

Tags: postman, json-value

I have a scenario to validate the "status" value in the array. The response is dynamic and # iteration may vary. I don't want to save this value in my postman environment but need to make a dynamic check. From my below API Response, I got 2 instances, 1st with AVAILABLE, 2nd with SOLDOUT. Can someone suggest to me how do I make the comparison?

Response API:

```
[
    {
        "status": "AVAILABLE",
        "price": {
            "baseAveragePrice": 209,
            "discountedAveragePrice": 209
        },
        "Fee": 39,
        "flag": false
    },
    {
        "status": "SOLDOUT",
        "price": {
            "baseAveragePrice": 209,
            "discountedAveragePrice": 209
        },
        "Fee": 39,
        "flag": true
    },
]
```

---

```
pm.test("status Check", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.status).to.be.oneOf(["AVAILABLE", "SOLDOUT", "NOTRELEASED"]);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic check? also, your response returning an array, hence `jsonData.status` won't give you actual status. You have to make it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to check all of the `status` value in the response, you could iterate through them like this:

```
pm.test("status Check", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    _.each(jsonData, (arrItem) => {            
        pm.expect(arrItem.status).to.be.oneOf(["AVAILABLE", "SOLDOUT", "NOTRELEASED"]);
    })
});
```

Comment: ah, I didn't see your answer, before posting a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet is actually working for one single element.
Your current response is a JSON-array. So you need to iterate your check over the whole array.

One solution ist this:

```
pm.test("status Check", function() {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    jsonData.forEach(function(arrayElement) {
        pm.expect(arrayElement.status).to.be.oneOf(["AVAILABLE", "SOLDOUT", "NOTRELEASED"]);
    });

});
```

This will return one single Test "status Check" with OK, if all of them are ok, and with FAILED if one of them fails.

[image: one single test]

If you want to see more details in your test-result, i would suggest to add each one of them in one nested test. With this solution you will have 3 Tests. One general Test "status Check" and one test for each Array item (in this case 2):

```
pm.test("status Check", function() {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    jsonData.forEach(function(arrayElement) {
        pm.test("Status is either 'AVAILABLE','SOLDOUT' or 'NOTRELEASED'", function() {
            pm.expect(arrayElement.status).to.be.oneOf(["AVAILABLE", "SOLDOUT", "NOTRELEASED"]);
        });
    });

});
```

[image: one test per array-item]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's been explained a lot better and not just a solution, like mine.

Comment: @SankarS, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/342092) if it solved your problem,